# How to get multiple view's dimention with onLayout just with one function in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a grid scene which contains 4*4 view boxes.
I want to get each one's dimension to see if the user moves his/her finger on them or not.
I succeed in this process by writing 16 separated 'onLayout' functions for my 16 boxes and then tried to calculate user touch movements.
Also, I write 16 view UI instead of a clean for loop for that.

So I ended up with some messy dirty codes that can not be used dynamically and won't be implementable.
can anyone help me to clean this code with a function and a loop?

This is what I have:

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{flex : 1}}><Text>{this.state.wordObj['A']}</Text></View>
      <View onLayout={this.getExactPos} style={{flex : 4, backgroundColor: 'red', marginLeft:20,marginRight:20}} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}  >
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 , backgroundColor: 'red', width: '100%'}}>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosA} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box1}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosB} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'orange', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box2}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosC} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'gray', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box3}</Text></View>
        </View>
        <View onLayout={this.getExactPosRow2} style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 , backgroundColor: 'blue' , width: '100%'}}>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosD} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'green', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box4}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosE} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'red', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box5}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosF} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box6}</Text></View>
        </View>
        <View onLayout={this.getExactPosRow3} style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 , backgroundColor: 'green', width: '100%'}}>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosG} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'purple', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box7}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosH} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box8}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosI} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: '#124567', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box9}</Text></View>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex : 1}}><Text>3</Text></View>
    <Text>Hello world! - Home</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor : 'red'}} onPress={this._signOutAsync}>
        <Text>Log Out</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity> 
  </View>
);  }
```

and this Part is view's onLayout functions:

```
getExactPos = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;   
    this.setState({
      gridXstart : x,
      gridXend : x + width,
      gridYstart : y,
      gridYend : y + height,
    })
    // alert(x);
  };

  getExactPosRow2 = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;   
    this.setState({         
      row2Y : y,        
    })       
  };

  getExactPosRow3 = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;   
    this.setState({         
      row3Y : y,        
    })       
  };

  getExactPosA = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout; 
    let newArray = this.state.a;
      newArray.gridXstart = x;
      newArray.gridXend = x + width;
      newArray.gridYstart = y;
      newArray.gridYend = y + height;
    this.setState({a: newArray});
  }; 

  getExactPosB = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;   
    let newArray =this.state.b;
      newArray.gridXstart = x;
      newArray.gridXend = x + width;
      newArray.gridYstart = y;
      newArray.gridYend = y + height;
    this.setState({b: newArray});
  };

  getExactPosC = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;   
    let newArray = this.state.c;
      newArray.gridXstart = x;
      newArray.gridXend = x + width;
      newArray.gridYstart = y;
      newArray.gridYend = y + height;
    this.setState({c: newArray});
  };

  getExactPosD = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;   
    let newArray = this.state.d;
      newArray.gridXstart = x;
      newArray.gridXend = x + width;
      newArray.gridYstart = y;
      newArray.gridYend = y + height;
    this.setState({d: newArray});
  };

  getExactPosE = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;   
    let newArray = this.state.e;
      newArray.gridXstart = x;
      newArray.gridXend = x + width;
      newArray.gridYstart = y;
      newArray.gridYend = y + height;
    this.setState({e: newArray});
  };

  getExactPosF = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;   
    let newArray = this.state.f;
      newArray.gridXstart = x;
      newArray.gridXend = x + width;
      newArray.gridYstart = y;
      newArray.gridYend = y + height;
    this.setState({f: newArray});
  };

  getExactPosG = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;   
    let newArray = this.state.g;
      newArray.gridXstart = x;
      newArray.gridXend = x + width;
      newArray.gridYstart = y;
      newArray.gridYend = y + height;
    this.setState({g: newArray});
  };

  getExactPosH = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;   
    let newArray = this.state.h;
      newArray.gridXstart = x;
      newArray.gridXend = x + width;
      newArray.gridYstart = y;
      newArray.gridYend = y + height;
    this.setState({h: newArray});
  };

  getExactPosI = e => {
    const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;   
    let newArray = this.state.i;
      newArray.gridXstart = x;
      newArray.gridXend = x + width;
      newArray.gridYstart = y;
      newArray.gridYend = y + height;
    this.setState({i: newArray});
    //alert('asdasdas')
  };
```

I want to use this kind of loop to create my grid dynamically and also one onLayout fuction to handle all. :

```
let rows = [];        
    let k = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i<4 ; i++){
        let row= [];
        for(let j = 0; j<4; j++){
           k++;
           row.push(
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPos2} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box1}</Text></View>
           )     
        }
        rows.push(
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 , backgroundColor: 'red', width: '100%'}}>{row}</View>
        )
    }
```

And for detecting user touch movement on boxes(like piano) I tried to get user's finger location on screen and compare with each boxes location. that is because I couldn't find any solution that each box itself always listen for touch movement.

here is my code for gesture handling: I use panResponder for parent view.

```
<View onLayout={this.getExactPos} style={{flex : 4, backgroundColor: 'red', marginLeft:20,marginRight:20}} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}  >
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 , backgroundColor: 'red', width: '100%'}}>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosA} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box1}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosB} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'orange', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box2}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosC} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'gray', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box3}</Text></View>
        </View>
        <View onLayout={this.getExactPosRow2} style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 , backgroundColor: 'blue' , width: '100%'}}>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosD} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'green', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box4}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosE} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'red', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box5}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosF} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box6}</Text></View>
        </View>
        <View onLayout={this.getExactPosRow3} style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 , backgroundColor: 'green', width: '100%'}}>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosG} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'purple', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box7}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosH} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box8}</Text></View>
            <View onLayout={this.getExactPosI} style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor: '#124567', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><Text>{this.state.Box9}</Text></View>
        </View>
      </View>
```

here is my panResponder function:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (evt) => {
        this.setState({
          zone: '',
        });
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        const drag = this.getDirectionAndColor(gestureState);
        this.setState({
          zone: drag ,
        });                      
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        this.setState({
          zone: 'Finished',
        });            
      },
    });
  }
```

and here is my calculation function:

```
 getDirectionAndColor = ({ moveX, moveY, dx, dy, x0, y0, stateID }) => {  

          if(
            (this.state.a.gridXstart+this.state.gridXstart < moveX)
            &&          
            (moveX < this.state.a.gridXend + this.state.gridXstart)
            &&
            (this.state.a.gridYstart+this.state.gridYstart < moveY)
            &&
            (moveY < this.state.a.gridYend + this.state.gridYstart)     
            ){           
             return this.state.Box1;
           }else if(
             (this.state.b.gridXstart+this.state.gridXstart < moveX)
             &&          
             (moveX < this.state.b.gridXend + this.state.gridXstart)
             &&
             (this.state.b.gridYstart+this.state.gridYstart < moveY)
             &&
             (moveY < this.state.b.gridYend + this.state.gridYstart)
           ){
             return this.state.Box2;
           }else if(
             (this.state.c.gridXstart+this.state.gridXstart < moveX)
             &&          
             (moveX < this.state.c.gridXend + this.state.gridXstart)
             &&
             (this.state.c.gridYstart+this.state.gridYstart < moveY)
             &&
             (moveY < this.state.c.gridYend + this.state.gridYstart)
           ){
             return this.state.Box3;
           }else if(
             (this.state.d.gridXstart+this.state.gridXstart < moveX)
             &&          
             (moveX < this.state.d.gridXend + this.state.gridXstart)
             &&
             (this.state.d.gridYstart+this.state.gridYstart+this.state.row2Y < moveY)
             &&
             (moveY < this.state.d.gridYend + this.state.gridYstart + this.state.row2Y)
           ){
             return this.state.Box4;
           }else if(
             (this.state.e.gridXstart+this.state.gridXstart < moveX)
             &&          
             (moveX < this.state.e.gridXend + this.state.gridXstart)
             &&
             (this.state.e.gridYstart+this.state.gridYstart+this.state.row2Y < moveY)
             &&
             (moveY < this.state.e.gridYend + this.state.gridYstart + this.state.row2Y)
           ){
             return this.state.Box5;
           }else if(
             (this.state.f.gridXstart+this.state.gridXstart < moveX)
             &&          
             (moveX < this.state.f.gridXend + this.state.gridXstart)
             &&
             (this.state.f.gridYstart+this.state.gridYstart+this.state.row2Y < moveY)
             &&
             (moveY < this.state.f.gridYend + this.state.gridYstart + this.state.row2Y)
           ){ 
             return this.state.Box6;
           }else if(
             (this.state.g.gridXstart+this.state.gridXstart < moveX)
             &&          
             (moveX < this.state.g.gridXend + this.state.gridXstart)
             &&
             (this.state.g.gridYstart+this.state.gridYstart+this.state.row2Y+ this.state.row2Y < moveY)
             &&
             (moveY < this.state.g.gridYend + this.state.gridYstart + this.state.row2Y+ this.state.row2Y)
           ){
             return this.state.Box7;
           }else if(
             (this.state.h.gridXstart+this.state.gridXstart < moveX)
             &&          
             (moveX < this.state.h.gridXend + this.state.gridXstart)
             &&
             (this.state.h.gridYstart+this.state.gridYstart+this.state.row2Y+ this.state.row2Y < moveY)
             &&
             (moveY < this.state.h.gridYend + this.state.gridYstart + this.state.row2Y+ this.state.row2Y)
           ){
             return this.state.Box8;
           }else if(
             (this.state.i.gridXstart+this.state.gridXstart < moveX)
             &&          
             (moveX < this.state.i.gridXend + this.state.gridXstart)
             &&
             (this.state.i.gridYstart+this.state.gridYstart+this.state.row2Y+ this.state.row2Y < moveY)
             &&
             (moveY < this.state.i.gridYend + this.state.gridYstart + this.state.row2Y+ this.state.row2Y)
           ){
             return this.state.Box9;
           }else{
             return 'No'
           }        
  };
```

here is my state:

```
state = { 
    zone: "Still Touchable",      
    gridXstart : 0,
    gridXend : 0,
    gridYstart : 0,
    gridYend : 0,
    row2Y: 0,
    row3Y: 0,
    Box1: 'A',Box2: 'B', Box3: 'C', Box4: 'D', Box5: 'E',Box6: 'F',Box7: 'G', Box8: 'H', Box9: 'I',
    wordObj : {},
    a : {
      gridXstart : 0,
      gridXend : 0,
      gridYstart : 0,
      gridYend : 0,
    },
    b : {
      gridXstart : 0,
      gridXend : 0,
      gridYstart : 0,
      gridYend : 0,
    },
    c : {
      gridXstart : 0,
      gridXend : 0,
      gridYstart : 0,
      gridYend : 0,
    },
    d : {
      gridXstart : 0,
      gridXend : 0,
      gridYstart : 0,
      gridYend : 0,
    },
    e : {
      gridXstart : 0,
      gridXend : 0,
      gridYstart : 0,
      gridYend : 0,
    },
    f : {
      gridXstart : 0,
      gridXend : 0,
      gridYstart : 0,
      gridYend : 0,
    },
    g : {
      gridXstart : 0,
      gridXend : 0,
      gridYstart : 0,
      gridYend : 0,
    },
    h : {
      gridXstart : 0,
      gridXend : 0,
      gridYstart : 0,
      gridYend : 0,
    },
    i : {
      gridXstart : 0,
      gridXend : 0,
      gridYstart : 0,
      gridYend : 0,
    },         
  };
```

Please help me with some advises.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it with one `onLayout` function as you use two distinct functions in your current setup. So it is possible to do it with two. You just need to abstract the code a little further and then it is possible to make it work.

If we think of grid you are constructing like this, we can easily find each cell in the grid if we follow a straight forward naming convention `XY`, where `X` is the row and `Y` is the column.

```
+----+----+----+
| 11 | 12 | 13 |
+----+----+----+
| 21 | 22 | 23 |
+----+----+----+
| 31 | 32 | 33 |
+----+----+----+
```

Using that idea we can modify your two `onLayout` functions to be something like this:

```
getExactPos = (e, key) => { // pass a key as well now
  const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;
  let position = {};
  position.gridXstart = x;
  position.gridXend = x + width;
  position.gridYstart = y;
  position.gridYend = y + height;
  this.setState({ [key]: position }); // notice that we use the key to store it in state
}

getExactPosRow = (e, key) => {  // pass a key as well now
  const { y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;
  this.setState({ [key]: y });  // notice that we use the key to store it in state
};
```

We will set the keys used in these function in the `constructViews` function below. Now with these we can construct a function that will in turn construct the grid:

```
constructViews = () => {
  let rows = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    let row = [];
    for (let j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
      let stateKey = `${i}${j}`;
      let styleKey = `box${stateKey}`;
      row.push(
        <View onLayout={ (e) => this.getExactPos(e, stateKey)} style={styles[styleKey]} key={stateKey}><Text>{this.state[styleKey]}</Text></View>
      );
    }
    rows.push(
      <View onLayout={e => this.getExactPosRow(e, `${i}`)} style={styles[`row${i}`]} key={i}>{row}</View>
    );
  }
  return rows;
}
```

In this function we have a nested `for-loop` that constructs the grid. Notice that we construct and pass keys to the two `onLayout` functions that we created. We can extend the idea of using keys further by dynamically getting the correct styles and the correct text.

Here is it in a working POC. This should give you enough to implement what you want. I haven't implemented any gesture responders and will leave that up to you.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    box11: 'Box 11',
    box12: 'Box 12',
    box13: 'Box 13',
    box21: 'Box 21',
    box22: 'Box 22',
    box23: 'Box 23',
    box31: 'Box 31',
    box32: 'Box 32',
    box33: 'Box 33'
  }

    getExactPos = (e, key) => {
      const { width, height, x, y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;
      let position = {};
      position.gridXstart = x;
      position.gridXend = x + width;
      position.gridYstart = y;
      position.gridYend = y + height;
      this.setState({ [key]: position });
    }

  getExactPosRow = (e, key) => {
    const { y } = e.nativeEvent.layout;
    this.setState({
      [key]: y
    });
  };

  constructViews = () => {
    let rows = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
      let row = [];
      for (let j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
        let stateKey = `${i}${j}`;
        let styleKey = `box${stateKey}`;
        row.push(
          <View onLayout={ (e) => this.getExactPos(e, stateKey)} style={styles[styleKey]} key={stateKey}><Text>{this.state[styleKey]}</Text></View>
        );
      }
      rows.push(
        <View onLayout={e => this.getExactPosRow(e, `${i}`)} style={styles[`row${i}`]} key={i}>{row}</View>
      );
    }
    return rows;
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}></View>
        <Button onPress={() => console.log(this.state)} title={'console log state'} />
        <View style={{ flex: 4, backgroundColor: 'red', marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20 }} >
          {this.constructViews()}
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row1: { flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', width: '100%' },
  row2: { flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', width: '100%' },
  row3: { flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green', width: '100%' },
  box11: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
  box12: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'orange', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
  box13: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'gray', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
  box21: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
  box22: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
  box23: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
  box31: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'purple', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
  box32: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
  box33: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#124567', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }
});
```

Here you can see it working in this snack https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/dynamic-grid-using-onlayout

Comment: It works like a charm, I also tried to detect user's finger movement on boxes, and because I couldn't find any solution which each box listen for movement, so I used their location and user's finger movement location to find out where it is. I want to have a piano like experience. so I'l put my code here, If you could please help me to improve it or use another solution.

Comment: I add my gesture handler code to the question.
I have two problem to implement it with your solution:
1- how to use another for loop to check where user's finger is.
2- I need to add boxes state after I get grid's size. mayber 4*4 maybe 10*10 ,... so I cant define boxes state at my code. some how I need to define it in that loop either.

Comment: 1) I’m not sure how you want to implement gesture handler so I cannot answer that question. 2) the code above can be abstracted further to handle any size grid. You just have to set the values before you call the loop so it has to be done in the constructor or componentDidMount. I think you’ve got the ability to figure out how to do the next abstraction. Just think about what is the main issue you are facing if you change the dimensions of the grid. There are only two issue to solve. Ask your self what are the initial text and the styles for each box?